# Php mysql query displaying data it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a project that involves getting flight information from a database.

I want the results to look like:

---

01 Nov 2017 - Eastern Airways 7601

Departing from Southampton, Eastleigh (SOU) at 0840

---

However my code seems to bring up the below with a mysterious live of nonsense as per below

---

01 Nov 2017 - Eastern Airways 7601

Departing from , () at 084001 Nov 2017 - 7601 //**this line I don't want**

Departing from Southampton, Eastleigh (SOU) at 0840

---

```
$link = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );

foreach ($flights as $b) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  '$airline' LIMIT 0 , 30;"; 
$query .= "SELECT * FROM  `airports` WHERE  `Airport Code` =  '$depdest' LIMIT 0 , 30;"; 
/* Execute queries */

if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
do {
/* store first result set */
if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


/* print results */    
{
        $date=date_create($depdate);
echo "<b>" . date_format($date,"d M Y"). " - ". $row['airlinename']." ".$flightno. "</b><br/>";


echo "Departing from " .$row['City Name'].", ".$row['Airport Name']." (".$row['Airport Code'].") at " . $deptime;

}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}   
} while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Data base tables are as below

**table 1 - Name "airports"**

Airport ID  City name   Airport Code    Airport Name    Country name    Country Abbrev. World Area Code

1,  108 Mile Ranch,     ZMH ,    108 Mile Ranch ,    Canada,         CA,        906,

2,  Aachen, AAH Aachen/Merzbruck,   Germany,    DE, 429,

3,  Aachen, ZIU,    Railway,    Germany,    DE, 429,

4,  Aalborg,    AAL,    Aalborg,    Denmark,    DK, 419,

etc

**table 2 - Name "airlines"**

airline id, Iata,   Airline Name

1,  0A, Amber Air,

2,  0B, Blue Air,

3,  0C, IBL Aviation,

etc

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your database tables from which you want to retrieve data from?

Comment: Ok, added database tables as per your request!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using multiple query statements? Wouldn't using UNION be easier for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I was to guess, I would say that there is a problem with the $b variable.

It seems your output is being written twice: the value "084001" in the middle of the second line looks to be the 0840 flight time from one entry, and then immediately starting the next entry as the date.

I would guess that the foreach is looping twice, instead of once, causing two outputs.

Could you do an output of the $b variable?

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Ok, I'm getting somewhere,   If i do print_r($b); I get Array ( [0] => 765 [1] => SQ [2] => Singapore Airlines ) Array ( [0] => 3358 [1] => Hong Kong [2] => HKG [3] => Hong Kong International [4] => China [5] => HK [6] => 729 )      - This looks like there's two arrays under the $b variable which is causing the duplicate - But i still can't fix it.

Comment: Two arrays under $b. Is this expected? If not, I would go back to find out where $b is being set.